# How can I use Akaike's Information Criterion to compare two models of multi-peaked emission spectra?

Tags: model-selection, aic, fitting, spectral-analysis

I have several photoluminescence emission spectra that I am trying to fit curves to. The spectra each have a slight baseline and four peaks. The independent variable $x_i$ is wavelength (converted to energy for analysis) and the response variable $y_i$ is intensity of light recorded at that wavelength. The experimental errors are assumed to be $\sigma_i = \sqrt{y_i}$ .

I'm fitting these data with two different models. Model 1 has four Gaussian peaks and a baseline of "$y = mx + c$ type", i.e. 14 parameters in total. Model 2 is again four peaks + linear baseline, but this time the each peak is fitted with a pseudo-Voigt function whose parameters are area, "mixing", mean, and FWHM, meaning a total of 18 parameters for the second function.

The fits are quite similar but there are slight differences, with Model 2 seeming to be a slightly better fit to every spectrum in the dataset. I would like to use the AICc to compare the models, because I wish to ascertain whether the Model 2 fit is genuinely a better representation of the physical processes that generate the spectra, or if it is just overparameterized. But I don't know the likelihood functions or how to calculate or maximize them.

I looked [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#Chi-squared_fits) and thought that perhaps I could use the $\chi^2$ values from each fit to calculate the AIC in the absence of a maximum likelihood estimate. But I am not sure that the assumption "that the underlying errors are normally distributed (with mean zero) and independent" is met here. If "underlying errors" refers to the residuals after each fit, they do seem to have normal distributions (but not with mean zero); if it actually refers to the experimental errors, then there is not a normal distribution (see above).

I don't really understand what "likelihood function" means in the context of photoluminescence emission spectra. After all, the spectra are not records of events following a binomial probability distribution like the coin toss, or a Poissonian probability distribution like the electronic shot noise, that seem to be the bases of all the examples I could find. I am at a loss how to understand the probability mass function in this case. Is it justifiable to use the model functions as the probability mass functions and derive the likelihood functions from them, or is that just circular logic? I'd be grateful for any advice.